# PHP Image Upload MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

Trying since some days to clear my Error with uploading an Image to a Folder and link to MySQL. I posted already my Problem but changed some codes thats why i want to post it again. Sorry if i spam.

This is my Code "adresse-bearbeiten.php"

```
<?php 
require_once ('konfiguration.php');
$target = "images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

    function sanitize( $input ){
    return mysql_real_escape_string( htmlspecialchars( stripslashes( trim( $input ) ) ) ); 
    }

    if(isset($_POST['title']))
        {

            $title          = sanitize($_POST['title']);
            $description    = sanitize($_POST['description']);
            $applepart      = sanitize($_POST['applepart']);
            $partnumber     = sanitize($_POST['partnumber']);
            $productcode    = sanitize($_POST['productcode']);
            $compatibility  = sanitize($_POST['compatibility']);
            $image          = sanitize($_FILES['photo']['name']);
            $price          = sanitize($_POST['price']);
            $insert         = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `adressbuch` (`title`,`description`,`applepart`,`partnumber`,`productcode`,`compatibility`,`photo`,`price`) VALUES ('$title','$description','$applepart','$partnumber','$productcode','$compatibility','$image','$price')");


            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
            {

            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
            }
            else {

            echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
            }

            if (!$insert)
            {
              die('Not saved: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    }
?>

        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
          <span>Neuer Eintrag:</span> <br />
          <span>Title</span><input type="text" name="title" /> <br />
          <span>Description</span><textarea cols="16" rows="5"  name="description"></textarea> <br />
          <span>Apple Part</span><input type="text" name="applepart" /> <br />
          <span>Part Number</span><input type="text" name="partnumber" /> <br />
          <span>Product Code</span><input type="text" name="productcode" /> <br />
          <span>Compatibility</span><input type="text" name="compatibility" /> <br />
          <span>Image</span><input type="file" name="photo" /> <br />
          <span>Price</span><input type="text" name="price" /> <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Speichern"/> <br />
        </form>
```

The MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adressbuch` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text,
  `description` text,
  `applepart` text,
  `partnumber` text,
  `productcode` text,
  `compatibility` text,
  `photo` text,
  `price` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;
```

The Errors i get is listed below

- Notice: Undefined index: photo in
  /Users/fatih/Sites/phpform/neu/adresse-bearbeiten.php on line 11
- Notice: Undefined index: photo in
  /Users/fatih/Sites/phpform/neu/adresse-bearbeiten.php on line 18
- Notice: Undefined index: photo in
  /Users/fatih/Sites/phpform/neu/adresse-bearbeiten.php on line 23
- Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.

Would be happy if someone can tell me what am i doing wrong?
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check the following things:

1. Is your form's `enctype` set to `multipart/form-data`? It should be. (`<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`)
2. What happens when you do an `echo '<pre>';print_r($_FILES);exit;` somewhere in your code? Does it output some info about your uploaded files? It should.

Comment: his form is not multipart/form-data

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that HTML at the bottom there. Yes, kara, I can't guarantee that your code will work WITH the proper `enctype`, but I can guarantee that it won't work WITHOUT it.

Comment: Jason thanks i got it solved. Could not see the missing part of multipart/form-data. I have added it to the form an all has been solved.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked apache error log? Do you have permissions on target folder?

I've been working with a similar system in the company I work, and the common errors I had were:

1) Permissions on target folder
1.1) www-data must have permissions on target folder (If you run Linux)
2) Apache configuration in site definition (sites-enabled folder) where you set some directives, for example root_dir. This way Apache can restrict access to folders that aren't inside root_dir. (example /var/www).

```
Make a print_r($_FILES);
```

Do a check with **isset** to see if there is anything coming, else put something.

Example:

```
 $T3 = isset($_POST['T3']) ? $_POST['T3'] : NULL;
```

Have you checked PHP reference for the error? **photo** is unset, which means this value isn't coming and you are trying to use it.